# Creating polygon grid using fixed extent

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, scale, vector-grid

I have a Shapefile of a town. I would like to divide the whole area into grids such that each grid has a scale of 1:2000. I have set my map to fixed scale (1:2000) in Layout View.

Comment: In this case go to data view, and use fishnet tool http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000

Answer (score 1):

You can create a grid of polygons for a set extent using the Grid Index Features tool (*Cartography Tools > Data Driven Pages toolbox*). The town shapefile will be the Input Features, make sure the 'Use Page Unit and Scale' option is checked, and enter the map scale. You can limit the output grid features to only areas wghic